# Is there a better way in achieving similar results in Pandas or using any other library in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Basically there are two data sets Global and Local, which has around 65,000 rows each. I am trying to merge both the data sets based on a primary key in Global data.

```
Global:

Primary key      Name
234            ABC ltd
344            GHF ltd
566            THD ltd
677            FGG ltd
4666           JKD ltd


Local:

Primary key      Country     Status       Date
234                USA     Completed    1/8/2018
234                CAN     Pending      3/5/2019
344                USA     Pending      8/8/2019
344                CAN     Completed    6/5/2018
566                USA     Pending      3/5/2019
566                CAN     Completed    8/8/2019
677                USA     Pending      8/8/2019
4666               USA     Completed    1/8/2018
4666               CAN     Completed    1/8/2018

Merge:
Primary key      Name        USA Status  USA Date  CAN Status   CAN Date   
234            ABC ltd   Completed    1/8/2018     Pending      3/5/2019
344            GHF ltd   Pending      8/8/2019     Completed    6/5/2018
566            THD ltd   Pending      3/5/2019     Completed    8/8/2019
677            FGG ltd   Pending      8/8/2019        -            -
4666           JKD ltd   Completed    1/8/2018     Completed    1/8/2018
```

So here I have shown only two countries for example whereas I am dealing with four regions.

For this I have split the Local data set into two different data frames and then merged it with the global data. Codes below for what I have done so far.

```
import pandas as pd

Global = pd.read_excel("path to upload global data")
Local = pd.read_excel("path to upload local data")

df1 = Local.loc[Local['Country'] == "USA"]
df2 = Local.loc[Local['Country'] == "CAN"]

usa = df1.rename(columns={"Status": "USA Status", "Date": "USA Date"})
can = df2.rename(columns={"Status": "CAN Status", "Date": "CAN Date"})

r1 = pd.merge(Global,usa,on = "Primary Key",how = "left")
result = pd.merge(r1,can,on = "Primary Key",how = "left")
```

It looks neat with just two but with multiple regions it slows down the processing time and also cramp up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='key')
df = df.set_index(['key', 'name', 'country']).unstack('country')
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: x[1])]

print(df)
                 status      date     status      date
country             CAN       CAN        USA       USA
key  name                                             
234  ABC ltd    Pending  3/5/2019  Completed  1/8/2018
344  GHF ltd  Completed  6/5/2018    Pending  8/8/2019
566  THD ltd  Completed  8/8/2019    Pending  3/5/2019
677  FGG ltd        NaN       NaN    Pending  8/8/2019
4666 JKD ltd  Completed  1/8/2018  Completed  1/8/2018
```

Comment: Thanks for this Frank but I am getting a Value error:  Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: The error is telling you there are duplicate values in the data.  I'm going to assume the Primary key should be unique for status?                                      df = df1.merge(df2, on='Primary key').set_index(['Primary key', 'Name', 'Country']).drop_duplicates().unstack('Country')

Comment: Thanks Frank when I did df = df1.merge(df2, on='Primary key').set_index(['Primary key', 'Name', 'Country']).drop_duplicates().unstack('Country')  it worked